# Session clustering with Jetty-runner 8.1.14.v20131031

Tags: cluster, jetty, session, sticky-sessions

I'm using Jetty-runner 8.1.14.v20131031 and I would like to know what's the easiest way to achieve session clustering between multiples running instances.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is probably to use the jdbc session manager detailed here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-clustering-jdbc.html

I am having issues getting eclipse wiki to load so can't link the jetty 8 version of this doc, but it is largely the same.